# Retrieve all products that contains specific handle in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to retrieve list of products that have matching handles.
eg :I have four products having specific words similar in handle

```
2000-kawasaki-1100-stx-ajpc
2000-kawasaki-1100-stx-kjpc
2000-kawasaki-1100-stx-cpjc
2000-kawasaki-1100-stx-dfgc
```

Now i want to retrive products that contain 2000-kawasaki-1100-stx in handle.
i tried using

```
{{ all_products['2000-kawasaki-1100-stx'] }}
```

But this didnt work ,i cant also loop through all collection because of shopify limit.
Is there any way to get this work ?

Comment: Shopify liquid's API says `The all_products object has a limit of 20 unique handles per page. If you want more than 20 products, then consider using a collection instead.`.
Are your products in a specific collection?

Comment: @0xRyN No i dont have any products in a collection ,i have to filter them by handle

Answer (score 0):

as you say, the all_products object has a limit of 20 unique handles per page. If you want more than 20 products, then consider using a collection instead.

An example collection iteration:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}

{%- case product.id -%}
{%- when '123456' -%}

{% assign my_product = product %}
{% endcasae %}
{% endfor %}
```

instead of using "if" please use "case" so best code practice and fast result while searching on loop of around 50 iterations.

Comment: This didnt work @jmvcollaborator